# Como soluciono el problema de este método sobre búsqueda de arreglos?

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, condiciones

[image: error.]
Quiero buscar un elemento de un arreglo para después todo ese arreglo salga impreso, pero el método me marca error como se ve en la imagen
case 4:
Calificacion();
break;
case 5:
Buscar(Alumno[] obj1, Profesor[] obj2, Materia[] obj3, Cardex[] obj4);
break;
case 6:

```
public static void Buscar(Alumno[] obj1, Profesor[] obj2, Materia[] obj3, Cardex[] obj4)
{
    int numero = 0;
    int persona = 0;
    System.out.println("Buscar persona");
    System.out.println("¿Que alumno o maestro buscas:");
    System.out.println("1.-Alumno");
    System.out.println("2.-Profesor");
    System.out.println("3.-Materia");
    persona = sc.nextInt();
    if (persona == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Buscas un alumno");
            System.out.println("Ingrese su numero de control:");
            obj1[i].setNoCOntrol(sc.nextInt());
            if (obj1[i].getNoCOntrol() == obj1[i].getNoCOntrol())
            {
                 System.out.println(obj1[i]);
            }
        }

    } else if (persona == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("Buscas un maestro");
        System.out.println("Ingresa su nombre:");
        System.out.println("Ingresa su apellido paterno");
        System.out.println("Ingresa su apellido materno");
    } else if (persona == 3)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, en el switch case lo que hace es llamar el método `Buscar`, en este caso no necesita pasar los tipos de datos debería quedar `Buscar(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4)` donde todos los parámetros deben ser del tipo de datos que espera el método y deben estar definidos Saludos

Comment: Aún me marca error al establecer dentro de buscar el código,

Comment: Por favor mustre el error de ahora