# Como soluciono el problema en metodos Java al buscar un arreglo?

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Quiero buscar un arreglo en java en un método distinto, en el método donde lo busco ya codifique los arreglos que usare, pero en el switch case me marca error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como se ve en la imagen me marca ese error.
case 4:
Calificacion();
break;
case 5:
Buscar(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4);
break;
case 6:
Eliminar();

```
 public static void Buscar(Alumno[] obj1, Profesor[] obj2, Materia[] obj3, Cardex[] obj4)
{
    int numero = 0;
    int persona = 0;
    System.out.println("Buscar persona");
    System.out.println("¿Que alumno o maestro buscas:");
    System.out.println("1.-Alumno");
    System.out.println("2.-Profesor");
    System.out.println("3.-Materia");
    persona = sc.nextInt();
    if (persona == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < obj1.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Buscas un alumno");
            System.out.println("Ingrese su numero de control:");
            obj1[i].setNoCOntrol(sc.nextInt());
            if (obj1[i].getNoCOntrol() == obj1[i].getNoCOntrol())
            {
                 System.out.println(obj1[i]);
            }
        }

    } else if (persona == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("Buscas un maestro");
        System.out.println("Ingresa su nombre:");
        System.out.println("Ingresa su apellido paterno");
        System.out.println("Ingresa su apellido materno");
    } else if (persona == 3)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Le tienes que pasar los arreglos al nuevo método.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como soluciono el problema de este método sobre búsqueda de arreglos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483798/como-soluciono-el-problema-de-este-m%c3%a9todo-sobre-b%c3%basqueda-de-arreglos)

Comment: Seguramente no tienes declarado los objetos: obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4 dentro del método donde se encuentra tu switch